# React Native: How to combine GiftedChat and ScrollableTabView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-native

I'm trying to combine a few React Native components together, but I'm having some trouble. The GiftedChat component gets cut off once there are more than 10 messages in the view, and I'm not sure what style rules I need to change in order to have the text input field for the message to stay fixed to the bottom.
Digging into the component code for GiftedChat, I tried setting the Composer component inside to have absolute positioning to the bottom, but I had no luck. When I checked out the ScrollableTabView styles component, I have no idea where to start looking for the part I could edit since it's a pretty complex component.

Any suggestions on how to get these two components working together?

Here is a link to my index.ios.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScrollableTabView, {ScrollableTabBar, } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NativeAppEventEmmiter,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ListView,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
class whistle extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: []
    }
    this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 2,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 3,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 4,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 5,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 6,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 7,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 8,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 9,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
        {
          _id: 10,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 30, 17, 20, 0)),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
      };
    });
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <View>
             <ScrollableTabView
                   style={{marginTop: 20, }}
                   initialPage={0}
                   renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
                 >
                <View tabLabel='Conversation'>
                   <GiftedChat
                     messages={this.state.messages}
                     onSend={this.onSend}
                     user={{
                       _id: 1,
                     }}
                   />
                </View>
             </ScrollableTabView>
        </View>
      );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('whistle', () => whistle);
```

Comment: random guess, but tried adding gifted chat within a `ScrollView`?

Comment: @Kreitzo yup, I have tried that but it's still pushing the text input for GiftedChat down... I think the ScrollView doesn't work since it's already inside the ScrollableTabView component... It's possible I'm not implementing it right though.

Comment: having a look now